# C++ how to initialize vector member from list of values

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to initialize a vector member variable with an array of integers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int arr[]) : mvec(arr)
    { }
    std::vector<int> mvec;
};

int main()
{
    A s({1,2,3});
}
```

Compilation gives me error :

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 try59.cpp

try59.cpp:15:12: note: candidates are:
try59.cpp:6:1: note: A::A(int*)
 A(int arr[]) : mvec(arr)
```

How can I initialize my vector using an array of integers?

Comment: `{1,2,3}` is not an array, it's an initialization list. `int arr[]` is not an array, it's a pointer to `int`

Comment: Where is the size of your array?

Comment: How can we initialize a vector using initialization list? The vector needs to be initialized by the initialization list passed as aruments

Comment: Can you clarify in your question if you need to initialize the vector from an *array* or from an *initialization_list*?

Comment: Sorry I was unaware of initialization_list - I was assuming it to be an array

Comment: you want the code in your question fixed and array was just a misunderstanding? In that case the title needs to be fixed. Its not your fault to have a wrong title (often thats part of knowing the answer), but for future readers it is an annoyment to have misleading titles

Comment: maybe "how to initialize vector member from list of values?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just use a `std::initializer_list` since that's what you're already passing

```
A(std::initializer_list<int> arr) : mvec(arr)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks it solves the issue - "by value" I assume it meant that remove the reference  const arr?

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you really want to initialize a vector using a C-style array and not `std::initializer_list`, you can do it using additional level of indirection:

```
struct A {
    template<std::size_t n>
    A(const int (&arr)[n]) :
        A(arr, std::make_index_sequence<n>{})
    { }

    template<std::size_t... is>
    A(const int (&arr)[sizeof...(is)], std::index_sequence<is...>) :
        mvec{arr[is]...}
    { }

    std::vector<int> mvec;
};

A a({1, 2, 3});
```

**Edit.** As **François Andrieux** pointed in the comment, `std::vector` can be initialized using a pair of iterators, so the constructor simplifies to:

```
template<std::size_t n>
A(const int (&arr)[n]) : mvec(arr, arr + n)
{ }
```

But if you were initializing, e.g., `std::array` instead of `std::vector`, `index_sequence` trick seems to be unavoidable.

Comment: If you were initializing a `std::array`, may as well take a `std::array` as a parameter, no?

Comment: @StoryTeller, sure. But OP took C-style array, and so did I.